# Countdown timer in php?

Tags: php, countdowntimer

I am a newbie to PHP. I want to add an countdown timer to my webpage.
Can someone please explain how can it be done?
Is there any function to do it?
I was thinking of using AJAX, But is there any simpler way?

Comment: What for you want to use it ? You should explain the case.

Comment: For instance, in a booking site, where the transaction must be completed with in say 3 / 4 minutes.

Comment: You don't need ajax for a countdown timer. Plain javascript should be enough.

Comment: Why not use Javascript then? Why do you want to do it on the server side?

Comment: Refer : http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

Comment: @anshu What do you want that happens when the time has elapsed?

Comment: If you want to synchronize it across all user sessions, there was a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645465/javascript-countdown-synchronize-on-different-browsers/15645486#15645486)

Comment: Also Refer : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: @Ikke Thanx buddy... ;) that thought din't strike..! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval

```
function init()
{
    updateCountdown();
    window.setInterval(updateTime,30000);
}

updateCountdown()
{
  //you code
}
```